# Progmatically Checking "CheckBoxCell" in DataGridView

Tags: c#, sql, datagridview

Currently my application will load items from the SQL database that the user can select from, they can then use the checkboxes to select which of these items are applicable to themselves, then can then save these selections and exit the window; this works fine.

I need to make my application fetch the user's previously saved selection, and then check the relevant boxes once the grid has been populated with all of the options (so **just** showing their selection).

I have the following code so far:

```
    private void LoadUserSelection()
    {
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(sys.gvConnectionString))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(qry.SelectUsersSelections(), conn))
            {
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SiteID", sys.gvSiteID);

                using (SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter())
                {
                    da.SelectCommand = cmd;

                    using (DataTable dt = new DataTable())
                    {
                        conn.Open();
                        da.Fill(dt);
                        conn.Close();

                        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in grdQueues.Rows)
                        {
                            foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
                            {
                                if (dr["ID"].ToString() == row.Cells["ID"].Value.ToString())
                                {
                                    DataGridViewCheckBoxCell chk = (DataGridViewCheckBoxCell)row.Cells[0];
                                    chk.Value = 1;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Hopefully this code make sense, it runs without issue, however even though the code does in fact hit the section to mark the checkbox as true it does not.

I have tried the following alternatives for **chk.Value = 1**

1. chk.Value = TrueValue;
2. chk.Selected = true;
3. chk.Value = true;

As this is a multi-user database, I cannot simply store boolean values against the pre-determined list, hence why the pre-determined list is fetched and populated first, and then I'm trying to action their previous selections.

***Note***: I'm not too sure what I'm doing above is even the best way to go around this, so as a bonus, if anyone has any tips on how I've nested the using statements or how I'm approaching this, it would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is correct using either of the two following options:

```
chk.Value = 1;    // Or...
chk.Value = true;
```

The only way I could duplicate this problem was if the `DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn` was manually added in the form constructor. Otherwise, when that column was also part of the original `DataTable` your code always worked in my tests. So assuming your workflow in that constructor is:

```
DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn col = new DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn();
// any col Properties manually set
dataGridView1.Columns.Add(col);

dataGridView1.AllowUserToAddRows = false;
dataGridView1.DataSource = LoadAllData();
LoadUserSelection();
```

You will see that `LoadUserSelection` correctly runs as expected, but due to binding behavior during construction you are not seeing the results. If you were to call your method anywhere else (like a `Button.Click` event) you'd probably see the results. If you want this behavior once the data is loaded, the following worked for me:

```
this.dataGridView1.DataBindingComplete += DataGridView1_DataBindingComplete;

private void DataGridView1_DataBindingComplete(object sender, DataGridViewBindingCompleteEventArgs e)
{
  this.LoadUserSelection();
}
```

Comment: This worked thank you! I forgot to mention that the checkboxes were added programmatically so thanks for testing.