# Cell from DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn Checked programmatically

Tags: c#, datagridview, checked, datagridviewcomboboxcell

I'm trying to check cells from a `DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn`.
I want to do it programmatically.

Here is my `DatagridView`:

```
DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn dataChecked = new DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn(false);

this.dataGrid.Columns.Add(dataChecked);
```

My `DataGrid` is using a `DataSource` from sql but my `CheckBoxColumn` doesn't. That column is just a way to know later when I have to add or remove some data to/from a container.

```
Container 
    DATA 1 Check
    DATA 2 Uncheck

Container 
    DATA 1 Uncheck (remove)
    DATA 2 Check (add)
```

I tried multiple things but nothing worked:

```
datagrid.Rows[1].Cells[5].Value = true;
datagrid.Rows[1].Cells[5].TrueValue = true;
DataGridViewCell chk = (DataGridViewCell)datagrid.Rows[1].Cells[5];
chk.Value = true;
```

I can tell if the cell is true or not but the `CheckBox` is not checked...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Progmatically Checking "CheckBoxCell" in DataGridView](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35709822/progmatically-checking-checkboxcell-in-datagridview)

Comment: I'm sorry this didn't occur to me before, but where are you setting these cell values to `true`? Because what you've tried should work, unless you are doing this is in the `Form` constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Try `chk.Value=1` for `true` or 0 for `false`.

Answer (score 0):

you can try follow code after adding value to datagridview checkbnox:

```
YourDataGridview.EndEdit();
```

With this sample:

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow r in MyDataGridView.Rows)
            {
                r.Cells["colSelection"].Value = true;
                MyDataGridView.EndEdit();
            }
```